# Standard error of standard deviation, skewness and kurtosis

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error

I want to use this formula (shown below) for my work (not math based) to calculate the uncertainty in the *sample standard deviation* (obtained from the link below):
[Calculating uncertainty in standard deviation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259383/calculating-uncertainty-in-standard-deviation)

$SE(\sigma) = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt(2N-2)}$

where $N$ is the size of the sample record.

However I cannot find any statistics books which cover this in anywhere? They all cover the standard error of the *mean*. The first sentence of the wikipedia article suggests that it should be possible to obtain a standard error for the standard deviation:

```
The standard error (SE) of a statistic (usually an estimate of a parameter) 
is the standard deviation of its sampling distribution[1] or an estimate of 
that standard deviation. If the parameter or the statistic is the mean, it 
is called the standard error of the mean (SEM).
```

Can anyone show me how this formula is derived and any simple(!) books which at least mention it?

Also, can a similar formula be found for standard error in kurtosis and skewness?

PS: I am not yet able to make a comment on the original thread. I made a previous question but it was asking too much so I'm asking again (with less stuff).

Comment: If you have a large data set of approximately independent and identically distributed experiments, then you can appeal to the CLT and Cochran's theorem that the sample variance, $S^2$, follows a scaled chi-square distribution, i.e. $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2\sim \chi_{n-1}^2$ (where $\sigma^2$ is the *true* variance). You can then use this to obtain confidence intervals on the variance $\sigma^2$ in terms of the point estimate, and hence also for standard deviation. See, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Confidence_interval_of_a_sampled_standard_deviation

Comment: Hi, yes, I have used this methodology to obtain confidence intervals already. But it is not trivial to go from the confidence interval to obtaining the absolute uncertainty as it is the case for confidence intervals for the mean.

Comment: If, for example, you look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps you can see that the confidence interval for the true mean is simply the sample mean plus/minus the standard error multiplied by its confidence level, C. You can then estimate the percentage uncertainty using this standard error. However the confidence interval of the standard deviation has no such quantity which you can use to obtain a percentage uncertainty. That is why I wanted to use the standard error of the standard deviation.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly: in the case of the mean, by "percentage uncertainty using the fractional error" you are just referring to taking the standard error, $z^* \cdot (\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ divided by the point estimate, $\bar{x}$? Then, you wish for something analogous for the case of estimating standard deviation? If so, my comment, indeed, is not too useful, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Or perhaps the other way around (the point estimate divided by the standard error of the point estimate).

Comment: A statistics book I was using said that one estimate for uncertainty is the standard error. This is the uncertainty in your measurement. You can also obtain a fractional uncertainty or a percentage uncertainty, using the standard error:
https://studynova.com/lecture/physics/measurement-and-uncertainty/absolute-fractional-percentage-uncertainty/

I therefore wanted to do something similar for the standard deviation. The formula in the post can probably(?) be used but I don't know from where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think it's quite what you were looking for, the following may be helpful.   In Mathematica, we can say things like:

```
In[1]:= Expectation[(Variance[{w, x, y, z}]-1)^2, {w \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
  z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]
Out[1]:= 2/3
```

If you try a few, you find that the expected variance comes out to be 2/(n-1)  (when the original normal distribution had a standard deviation of 1).  We can confirm this by Monte-Carlo methods.

```
In[2]:= Table[{N[2/(n - 1)], 
  Mean[Table[(Variance[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n]] - 1)^2,
     100000]]}, {n, 2, 20}]
Out[2]:= {{2., 2.02504}, {1., 0.990561}, {0.666667, 0.671811}, {0.5, 
  0.503348}, {0.4, 0.403083}, {0.333333, 0.335526}, {0.285714, 
  0.286752}, {0.25, 0.250503}, {0.222222, 0.22472}, {0.2, 
  0.200344}, {0.181818, 0.180828}, {0.166667, 0.168419}, {0.153846, 
  0.154251}, {0.142857, 0.141677}, {0.133333, 0.13277}, {0.125, 
  0.125321}, {0.117647, 0.117411}, {0.111111, 0.111469}, {0.105263, 
  0.104944}}
```

If we continue in this vein and consider the case where the standard deviation of the distribution, $\sigma$, isn't 1, we find the standard deviation of the variance for a sample of size $n$ is
$$
\sigma^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}
$$

This result and much more can be found in this useful summary paper: *Standard errors: A review and evaluation of standard error estimators using Monte Carlo simulations* (DOI: [10.20982/tqmp.10.2.p107](https://doi.org/10.20982/tqmp.10.2.p107))